# mysqli_query() warning parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given. database query failed

Tags: php

I am getting this warning:

```
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\inc\functions.php on line 73
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  251048  {main}( )   ..\manage_user.php:0
2   0.0012  295000  find_all_users( )   ..\manage_user.php:8
3   0.0012  295376  mysqli_query ( )    ..\functions.php:73
Database query failed.
```

I have read a few of the posts on it and from what understand the error is in the first string in my mysqli_query( $db , $query ).

This would be $db this is what i find strange.  mysqli_query($db,$query)works for all the other functions just fine. but when i call find_all_users() function i get the warning.

dbcon:

```
    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "*******");
    define("DB_PASS", "*******");
    define("DB_NAME", "*******");

  // 1. Create a database connection
  $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  // Test if connection succeeded
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . 
         mysqli_connect_error() . 
         " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
  }
```

functions:

```
function find_all_users() {
    global $db;
$query  = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM user ";
$query .= "ORDER BY username ASC";
$user_set = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    confirm_query($user_set);
    return $user_set;
}

function confirm_query($result_set) {
    if (!$result_set) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }
}
```

the page i am getting the warning on:

```
<?php 
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/session/session.php'); 
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/functions.php');
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/header.php');
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/nav_ribbon.php');
    $user_set = find_all_users();
?>

<body>
    <div id="p2dbg">
    <div id="p2dcontent">
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/left_container.php'); ?>
      <div id="page">
        <?php echo message(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you including `dbcon`?

Comment: You need to include / require `dbcon` before you can make a call to `find_all_users`

Comment: Are you setting `$db` as global in `dbcon`?

Comment: @AndrewJackman I do not think that is a requirement.  They do not need to be declared global, they just are because of their location. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: ok after 28 hours i cant see straight... thanks! i think i should go pass out now that i am making stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$db` was `null` because `dbcon` file was not being included:

```
include('dbcon.php');
session_start();
```